# Wordpress built-in pagination not working

Tags: wordpress, pagination

In the Wordpress reading options, I set it so that the index only displays 2 posts at most. However, the next and previous page buttons are missing. I went into my template, tried the default methods, and none of them worked.

I tried adding

```
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

Didn't work. I then tried

```
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?></div>
  <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries »') ?></div>
</div>
```

Which also didn't work. Nothing showed up in the source code of the final page, at all. These are default Wordpress functions, right? What is going wrong here?

If it's of any use, here's the index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="content">
    <ul class="items wrap">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <h4><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
        <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
        <hr>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, we couldn’t find the post you are looking for.'); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- I added the pagination code here. -->
    </ul>
</section>

<div id="delimiter"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were only two posts to display, so of course it didn't show the next/previous links. So there it is, problem solved.